# Parse a multi-line string into an array

Tags: julia

I'm trying to get my head around Julia, coming from Python. Currently working through some Project Euler problems I've solved using Python in Julia to get a better feeling for the language. One thing that I do a lot (in Project Euler and in real life) is to parse a big multiline data object into an array. For example, if I have the data

```
data = """1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 0 1 2"""
```

In python I might do

```
def parse(input):
    output = []
    for line in input.splitlines():
         output.append(map(int,line.split()))
    return np.array(output)
```

Here's what I have so far in Julia:

```
function parse(input)
    nrow = ncol = 0
    # Count first
    for row=split(input,'\n')
        nrow += 1
        ncol = max(ncol,length(split(row)))
    end

    output = zeros(Int64,(nrow,ncol))
    for (i,row) in enumerate(split(input,'\n'))
        for (j,word) in enumerate(split(row))
            output[i,j] = int(word)
        end
    end
    return output
end
```

What's the Julia version of "pythonic" called? Whatever it is, I don't think I'm doing it. I'm pretty sure there's a way to (1) not have to pass through the data twice, (2) not have to be so specific about allocating the array. I've tried hcat/vcat a little, without luck.

I'd welcome suggestions for solving this. I'd also be interested in references to proper Julia style (julia-onic?), and general language usage practices. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[readdlm](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=readdlm#Base.readdlm) is really useful here.  See the docs for all the options, but here's an example.

```
julia> data="1 2 3 4
       5 6 7 8
       9 0 1 2"
"1 2 3 4\n5 6 7 8\n9 0 1 2"

julia> readdlm(IOBuffer(data))
3x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
 5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
 9.0  0.0  1.0  2.0

julia> readdlm(IOBuffer(data),Int)
3x4 Array{Int32,2}:
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9  0  1  2
```